# mysqli_connect open/close every time or open once - efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am designing web application. It is built on AJAX and most AJAX calls require SQL enquiries to MySQL.

Currently on every PHP function (my AJAX call usually is one function), I do `mysqli_connect` at the beginning and at the end `close`.

Does it make sense to open it once, put it as a variable to session?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['con']))
   $_SESSION['con'] = mysqli_connect($mysql_server,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_database);
```

What do you think about the performance of `mysqli_connect`/`close`? How do you design this?

Comment: Resources can't be stored in session, because that requires serialization and resources can't be serialised: if you're really concerned about this, and it is demonstrably an overhead for you, consider persistent connections

Comment: What is the standart way to handle this? Open/close every time?

Comment: Yes, most apps do open/close every time: while it does take a bit of time to execute a connection, it's generally still fast enough for most websites... when it comes to database performance, badly formed queries or lack of indexes are far more likely to cost time and affect performance